# Issues with scikit-bio on Mac M1

Tags: skbio

I tried installing scikit-bio by running `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/biocore scikit-bio` per the documentation, but verifying the installation via `python -m skbio.test` yielded the following error: `Error while finding module specification for 'skbio.test' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbio')`.

Next, I tried installing with `pip install numpy` and `pip install scikit-bio`, but that yielded a huge wall of errors. Tried the installation test anyway, got the same ModuleNotFoundError.

I'm on a MacBook Air 2020 with a M1 processor, so not sure if that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still have problems with scikit-bio but the solution that worked for me was using sse2neon package: https://github.com/DLTcollab/sse2neon

Following instructions should work

```sh
git clone https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio
cd scikit-bio
wget https://github.com/DLTcollab/sse2neon/blob/master/sse2neon.h
```

Open the simde-sse2.h file and replace each of the following two lines:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
```

with:

```
#include "sse2neon.h"
```

then run:

```
pip install .
```

!Note that this solution doesn't work for newer python releases. I used python 3.8 for this solution.